# Pandas multiindex and constraint returns unalignable boolean series

Tags: pandas

Working with pandas multiindex and want to sort by secondary index and a constraint on a single column value.

```
        Local_X Local_Y v_Length    v_Width v_Class v_Vel   v_Acc   Lane_ID Preceding   Following   Space_Headway   Time_Headway    ewm_y   ewm_x   ewm_v   ewm_a
Vehicle_ID  Frame_ID                                                                
1   200 17.070  233.130 14.3    6.4 2   14.51   0.00    2   0   11  0.00    0.00    230.228002  17.035639   14.505089   0.463977
    201 17.087  234.581 14.3    6.4 2   14.51   0.00    2   0   11  0.00    0.00    231.679002  17.052759   14.505982   0.441342
    202 17.104  236.032 14.3    6.4 2   14.51   0.00    2   0   11  0.00    0.00    233.130001  17.069839   14.505803   0.419812
    203 17.121  237.482 14.3    6.4 2   14.51   0.00    2   0   11  0.00    0.00    234.580667  17.086893   14.505657   0.399332
    204 17.138  238.933 14.3    6.4 2   14.51   0.00    2   0   11  0.00    0.00    236.031445  17.103929   14.506447   0.379851
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
90  296 32.932  69.219  13.4    5.3 2   8.87    -0.85   3   86  0   58.82   6.63    67.578847   32.931133   8.951475    -0.178712
    297 32.933  70.093  13.4    5.3 2   8.85    0.35    3   86  0   58.95   6.66    68.426700   32.931763   8.910204    -0.094582
    298 32.930  70.970  13.4    5.3 2   8.97    1.88    3   86  0   59.07   6.59    69.281051   32.931170   8.897905    0.152664
    299 32.930  71.863  13.4    5.3 2   9.26    3.86    3   86  0   59.18   6.39    70.146146   32.930778   8.949272    0.514508
    300 32.945  72.801  13.4    5.3 2   9.67    4.80    3   86  0   59.22   6.12    71.034139   32.935535   9.091710    0.885495
```

I want to be able to sort out slices of Frame_ID that belong between values and where Lane_ID == cerrtain value.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
nl_df = trajec.loc[idx[:,200:300], :]
```

This above works to get the multiindex frame where Frame_ID fits certain values but cannot add in the lane_id consideration.

```
trajec.loc[idx[:,200:300], 'Lane_ID'] == 2
```

returns the boolean series but I want the entire dataframe for these conditions to be able to perform further analysis. I cannot however combine the 2 like with a normal dataframe and .loc for some reason.

I can perform the action in 2 lines by combining the 2 commands above but there probably is some way to solve with 1 line. I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I understood you correctly, maybe this line solves the problem?

```
df.loc[idx[df.loc[idx[:,:], 'Lane_ID'] == 2,200:300],:]
```

Comment: Yea, but I don't understand why the condition goes first in the idx order.

Comment: But this does solve my issue